# Question about some proof of that "Every orthonormal vectors are independent"

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the sentence saying that" Every $\mathbf{k}$ orthonormal vectors (from $\mathbb{R^n}$) are independent".
And the proof say the following:
" let's suppose they dependent, so there's an $\mathbf{x}\neq\mathbf{0}$ such that $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$ now we have that $A^TA\mathbf{x} = A^T\mathbf{0}=\mathbf{0}$ therefore, $A^TA\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$ therefore $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$".

My question is basic: Why is it allowed to multiply with $A^T$, we don't know that $A^T$ is invertible? Isn't this illegal?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi :) I guess the columns of $A$ are the orthonormal basis and the entries of $x$ are the coefficients for the linear combination. Then $A$ is an orthogonal matrix, i.e. $A^TA=I$ or equivalently for matrices in $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ we have $A^T=A^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More concretely, the matrix $A$ is a $n \times k$ matrix whose columns are orthonormal vectors, say $v_1, \dots, v_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$ that satisfy $v_i^T v_j = 1$ if $i = j$ and $v_i^T v_j = 0$ otherwise. So the matrix $A^T$ (or $A$) itself is not invertible: it is not even square. However, the Gram matrix $A^T A$ is invertible since we simply have $A^T A = I_k$ (the identity matrix in $\mathbb{R}^k$). We can verify this since the $(i, j)$th entry of the matrix $A^T A$ is simply $(A^T A)_{ij} = v_i^T v_j$.

So, we are allowed to multiply by $A^T$ since it does not matter whether it is invertible or not (for example, we can always multiply two sides of an equation by zero). The resulting expression that you obtain $A^T A x = 0$ then leads to a contradiction when we use the fact that the square matrix $A^T A$ is invertible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another proof that may interest you. I'll state it for arbitrary orthogonal vectors, not necessarily orthonormal vectors, but the proof is the same.

Suppose $S=\{\mathbf{x}_1,\cdots,\mathbf{x}_k\}$ is a set of nonzero orthogonal vectors inside $V$, and suppose $\sum_i a_i\mathbf{x}_i = \mathbf{0}$. Letting $\langle \bullet,\bullet \rangle$ be your inner product, apply $\langle \bullet,\mathbf{x}_1\rangle$ to this equation to get $\sum_i a_i \langle \mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{x}_1\rangle = 0$ by linearity in the first component. Since $\langle \mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{x}_1\rangle = 0$ for $i \neq 1$ and $\langle \mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_1\rangle \neq 0$, we see that $a_1=0$ since otherwise the sum is nonzero. Repeat with $\langle \bullet,\mathbf{x}_j\rangle$ for each $2 \le j \le k$ to see that $a_j = 0$ for all $j$, so the set is linearly independent.

This proof does not (directly) appeal to properties of orthogonal matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the Mathematics StackExchange, Maor!  I want to focus on the logical issue in your question of why it's allowed to multiply by $ A ^ \top $, although the answer by @JKL does address it too.

You're *always* allowed to perform the same well-defined operation to both sides of an equation, *if* your process of reasoning is ‹If the first equation is true, then the second equation is true› (that is, $ \mathrm { e q n } _ 1 \Rightarrow \mathrm { e q n } _ 2 $).  If instead you want to say ‹The first equation is true if and only if the second equation is true› (that is, $ \mathrm { e q n } _ 1 \Longleftrightarrow \mathrm { e q n } _ 2 $), *then* you need the operation to be invertible.

So here, the reasoning is ‹If $ A \mathbf x = \mathbf 0 $, then $ A ^ \top A \mathbf x = A ^ \top \mathbf 0 $, and then $ \mathbf x = \mathbf 0 $›.  That's what it means for the columns of $ A $ to be linearly independent.  While the overall converse ‹If $ \mathbf x = \mathbf 0 $, then $ A \mathbf x = \mathbf 0 $› is also true, this particular chain of reasoning would not be valid for that, since ‹If $ A ^ \top A \mathbf x = A ^ \top \mathbf 0 $, then $ A \mathbf x = \mathbf 0 $› (without knowing anything about $ A $ and $ \mathbf x $) is not correct.